# How to do batched dot product in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a input tensor that is of size `[B, N, 3]` and I have a test tensor of size `[N, 3]` . I want to apply a dot product of the two tensors such that I get `[B, N]` basically. Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
a = torch.randn(5, 4, 3)
b = torch.randn(4, 3)

c = torch.einsum('ijk,jk->ij', a, b) # torch.Size([5, 4])
```

Comment: Try not to use `einsum` unless you have to, because It's superbly slow. The second recommendation is way better.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
a = torch.randn(5, 4, 3)
b = torch.randn(4, 3)

c = (a * b[None, ...]).sum(dim=-1) # torch.Size([5, 4])
```

Comment: `b[None]` will suffice :)